# Unity inject PerRequestLifetimeManager with background tasks?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using Unity inject and like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IRepository<Log>, Repository<Log>>();
//....other repositories here...

container.RegisterType<ILogService, LogService>();
//...other services here...
```

And i have a task class like:

```
public class MyTaskClass
{

  LogService logService;

  public MyTaskClass(LogService logService)
  {
      this.logService = logService;
  }

  async void ExecuteTasks()
  {
      Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
         logService.Write("Test");
      });

      Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          logService.Write("Test");
      });

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
   }
}
```

and use container.Resolve method to create a MyTaskClass instance,but it will occur error that two task uses same dbcontext generated by DbContextFactory because of the PerRequestLifetimeManager,if I want to create different instance of dbcontext by unity so I have to register different lifetimemanager of IDbContextFactory ?

Thanks

Comment: If your factory always return the same instance then it is not a factory

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you simply didn't specify a LifetimeManager, or use the `TransientLifetimeManager`, which is the default. Each resolve will return a new instance. You use that, with and a combinaison of a method factory (A `Func<LogService>` injected in your `MyTaskClass` class) before you start the tasks, so each of them will have a different `DbContext`.